# Как я могу передавать динамическую информацию в свойства ActionFilter? (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: Использование фильтра в API-контроллере]

[image: Реализация фильтра]

Мне нужно сделать фильтр, который будет работать при редактировании записи (PATCH-запрос к WebAPI контроллеру). Фильтр должен создавать куки и записывать туда Id редактируемой записи.
Собиралась через HttpContext получить доступ к запросу, но свойства класса не воспринимаются атрибутом фильтра, как можно заметить на 58 строке.

Я в замешательстве, не знаю, что делать дальше и куда копать.

Comment: Пожалуйста , оформите код отдельно в вопросе, а не на скриншотах

Comment: `HttpContext` вроде доступен в `ActionExecutedContext ` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.httpcontext?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ControllerContext_HttpContext

Comment: `HttpContext` с большой буквы.